# How to execute tasks in the background without affecting the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I'm making some special Android Launcher, many clicks in the UI are supposed to do some heavy operations before the result is done. I don't want the UI to hang while that's executing.
I don't want to create a `Thread` on every job because that's resource intensive.

Note that I want the `Thread`s to be executed in the order they happened, one after another.

Comment: use a http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html with 1 thread, all requests will be queued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good strategy that works in cases like this is to create one thread whose only purpose is to:  "be the *boss."*  Uh huh, "there s/he is, just sitting' on his/her (!), not actually *doing* anything ...", **but**, this thread knows, at all times, what the current *overall workflow* looks like. Every other thread "asks the boss what to do next," and every other thread "reports to the boss the outcome of what has just been done."

The reason for this design is: "the *management* of a workflow" is usually **not** "an asynchronous activity." In fact, it is *prohibitively* "full of race-conditions," as we all have seen in any human-situation where "nobody's in charge."

Therefore:  "put *one* thread 'in charge.'"  *One thread* maintains the "to-do list."  Any subordinate thread can grab a "to-do" from the queue that this one thread is responsible for maintaining, and upon completion of that activity it *must* submit a status-report to "that one boss-thread."  Thus, "that one boss-thread," responding *serially* to various streams of requests, can effectively direct the activities of everyone else.

"That one thread" is the only authority who knows that "this app has been added to the sidebar."  (It was notified of this from a message on a *serialized* queue that *only it* reads.)  Based on this knowledge, it now creates one-or-more "to-dos," as the workflow-definition dictates.  Soon enough, some subordinate will pick up that to-do and "run with it," not knowing *why* it was posted.  (It doesn't have to "know why.")  It will, in due time, complete the work, post a completion-report to the "boss," and await further instructions.)

It's a strategy that works great for human activities.  So, it works equally well for computers, too.

Comment: Woah, nice strategy, even though I think it will not be easy to do such a thing with my knowledge, but i am willing to try and do it, tyvm

Answer (score 1):

The best way to communicate to your UI is to use an EventBus either from [Greebrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or from [Square](http://square.github.io/otto/).

[RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) is very good in bouncing between different threads, learning curve is quite high though.

[Android-Priority-Job-Queue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue) is also worth checking.